# python multiprocessing doesn't seem to be working with class

Tags: python, multiprocessing, zeromq, python-multiprocessing, pyzmq

I am trying to implement `zmq` client wrapper class. Hope the comments written are useful to understand. Please see the `__main__` for the different ways I tried.

```
import zmq

class Client(object):
    """
    This is class for passing message using pipeline(push-pull) pattern of zmq.

    """

    def __init__(self, pull_addr="tcp://127.0.0.1:5757",\
                push_addr="tcp://127.0.0.1:5858"):
        """
        The constructor

        Parameters:
        pull_addr (string) : Local endpoint for pushing messages and pulling from
        push_addr (string) : Remote endpoint for pushing messages.
        """
        super(Client, self).__init__()
        print("Initialized...")
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.push_addr = push_addr
        self.pull_addr = pull_addr

    def producer(self, msg):
        """
        Produces messages.

        It's a wrapper and will receive the message which will be queued locally by
        pushing to self.pull_addr. 

        Parameters:
        msg (json) : Messages to be queued.

        Returns:
        None
        """
        print("Production started.... ")
        zmq_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
        zmq_socket.bind(self.pull_addr)
        zmq_socket.send_json(msg)

    def consumer(self):
        """
        Consumes messages produced by self.producer.

        Reads messages queued by self.producer and pushes to the self.push_addr
        where it assumes the collector would be expecting messages.

        Parameters:
        None

        Returns:
        None
        """
        print("consumption is awaiting...")
        receiver = self.context.socket(zmq.PULL)
        receiver.connect(self.pull_addr)

        sender = self.context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
        sender.connect(self.push_addr)

        while True:
            msg = receiver.recv_json()
            sender.send_json(msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing
    # con_pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    # # pro_pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    zmq_client = Client()
    # consumer = con_pool.apply_async(zmq_client.consumer, ())
    # # producer = pro_pool.apply_async(zmq_client.producer,({"msg" : "Hello World!"}))
    # print("DONE>>>>")

    # from multiprocessing import Process
    # consumer = Process(target=zmq_client.consumer)
    # consumer.start()

    # producer = Process(target=zmq_client.producer, args=({'msg' : "Hello World!"}))
    # producer.start()
    # producer.join()
    # consumer.join()

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    p = pool.apply_async(zmq_client.consumer)
    p2 = pool.apply_async(zmq_client.producer, ({"msg" : "Hello World!"}))
```

**Try 1**

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
p = pool.apply_async(zmq_client.consumer) 
p2 = pool.apply_async(zmq_client.producer, ({"msg" : "Hello World!"}))
```

**Output 1**
    `calls the constructor and terminates.`

**Try 2**

```
con_pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pro_pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
zmq_client = Client()
consumer = con_pool.apply_async(zmq_client.consumer, ())
producer = pro_pool.apply_async(zmq_client.producer,({"msg" : "Hello World!"}))
```

**Output 2**

```
calls the constructor and terminates.
```

**Try 3**

```
from multiprocessing import Process
zmq_client = Client()
con = Process(target=zmq_client.consumer)
con.start()

pro = Process(target=zmq_client.producer, args=({'msg' : "Hello World!"}))
pro.start()
pro.join()
con.join()
```

**Output 3**

```
calls the constructor
calls the consumer
calls the producer
keeps hanging
```

Here I was expecting zmq server to receive the message. Any suggestions to get this class working as expected?

Comment: can you try the 3rd way, but you first create the 2 `Process`, then start them, then join them ?

Comment: @CoMartel Thanks for the response. Actually, the 3rd way was always working. It was me who was reading on `5557` instead of `5858`.  And yes without multiprocessing also it is working.

Comment: ok, so your problem is solved ?